# codeigniter FIND_IN_SET not working with join

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, find-in-set

I have a `codeigniter-mysql` requirement to select values from `table_2` which joins `table_1` and need to apply where statement in a comma separated field value. Tried as follows,

```
$where  =  $this->db->escape("FIND_IN_SET(table_1.id,table_2.places_id)<>0");

    $this->db->select('table_2.*,GROUP_CONCAT(table_1.location)AS location');
    $this->db->from('table_2');
    $this->db->join('table_1', $where);
    $this->db->where('ltable_2.packages_id', $id);
    $results = $this->db->get();
    return $results->result();
```

But the above codeigniter db object returns following mysql query and its not working :(

```
SELECT `table_2`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(table_1.location)AS location FROM `table_2` JOIN `table_1` ON 'FIND_IN_SET(table_1.id,table_2.places_id)<>0' WHERE `ltable_2`.`packages_id` = <id-goes-here>
```

It seems the quotes around `'FIND_IN_SET(table_1.id,table_2.places_id)<>0'` creates the problem! All helps are appreciated to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try with add false at last `$this->db->select('table_2.*,GROUP_CONCAT(table_1.location)AS location',FALSE);`

Comment: Why you are escaping `FIND_IN_SET` part ? just put as it is in `join()`

Comment: It would be nice to see the db error returned

Comment: tried 
$this->db->join('table_1', $where, false);
and 
$this->db->select('table_2.*,GROUP_CONCAT(table_1.location)AS location', FALSE);
but failed!
this will build query as follows,
SELECT table_2.*, GROUP_CONCAT(lgk_places.location)AS location FROM `table_2` JOIN `lgk_places` ON `FIND_IN_SET`(`lgk_places`.`id,table_2`.`places_id)<>0` WHERE `table_2`.`packages_id` =<id-goes-here>
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `table_2`.`packages_id` = '34' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Did you find any answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `$this->db->join('table_1', $where, false);`. That would get rid of the quotes, and if otherwise your query is good, it should be fine.